# Using retrieved information from my option tag to query my database for more information

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Been stocked here for a few hours now since i'm not very good on back-end.
i want to automatically display information in my input fields immediately a selection is been made. 
But then it only comes up when when i display it together in the selection tag.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>  
                                    <th width="40%">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
                                             <label for="doctor_id" class=" col-form-label">Enter ID</label>    
                                              <div class="form-group row">

                                <div class="col-xs-9">
                                   <select name="patid" class="chosen form-control">
                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select Patient</option>
                                        <?php 
                include '../db/db_connect.php';    

 $exp = "select * from addpat";      
 $expend = $connect->query($exp); 

while ($row=$expend->fetch_assoc())
{
echo " <option>" . $row['username'] ."</option>";
" <option>" . $row['fullname'] ."</option>";

}
?>


</select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".chosen").chosen();
</script>                                            


                <li><label for="doctor_id" class=" col-form-label">Fullname</label>
                    <input name="fullname"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Patient Name" value="">
                </li>  
                                            <li> 
                                            <label for="doctor_id" class=" col-form-label">Address</label>
                                                <input name="address"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
                                            </li>  
                                        </ul>
                                    </th>  
                                    <th width="20%" class="text-center"> 
                                        <strong style="border:1px solid #ccc;line-height:60px;padding:5px 10px;">Invoice</strong> 
                                    </th>  
                                    <th width="40%">
                                        <h4>
                                            Date :  
                                            <input name="dob" id="txtDate" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd"  placeholder="Date Of Birth"><br> 
                                            Amazing Grace<br> 
                                            98 Green rooad adad</h4>
                                    </th> 
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
```

Comment: ?? sorry, it's not clear what the problem is. _"But then it only comes up when when i display it together in the selection tag"_?

Comment: all you do now is to feed the select with options out of database. That looks fine so far. (expecting $connect to be defined somewhere before)

Comment: what is `$(".chosen").chosen();` doing?

Comment: used it for styling how i want the information in the option tag to look and also allow it work like a live search